# Distributed OSGi - what is the proper way to manage bundles across all containers?

Tags: java, osgi, distributed, provisioning, dosgi

We are considering utilizing distributed OSGi in our enterprise environment.
We would have the following setup:

- 10 to 100 OSGi containers on many hosts offer various services.
- Many of these services are provided by more than one container.
- Some of these services may require being consistent across all
  containers (same version deployed).

What is the proper way to manage bundles' lifecycle (install, start, update, stop, uninstall) across all containers?

Several requirements:

- As there may be so many containers, all of them should be handled
  together; i.e. when I am about to update a bundle, a single command
  should update all containers where that bundle already present.
- Commands must be repeatable: first perform a command on test systems, and then repeat the exact same command on production system once testing is complete.

I appreciate any suggestion regarding the above question.

Best regards,
Marton

Comment: Do all these OSGi containers build one big distributed OSGi container where service A on host X can use service B on host Y just like it would be on the same host X? or are they separated to each other and you have just 10-100 OSGi containers you want to maintain? and are they all the same like 10-100 OSGi containers having all exactly the same bundles and you want to send a command (like "install") to all these OSGi containers at the same time? Or are they different that host X have an OSGi container with N bundles and the OSGi container on host Y have a different set of bundles?

Comment: This is one big distributed OSGi environment: service A on host X can use service B on host Y. Each container may have a different set of bundles. Thanks!

Comment: I would try to build such system using Apache Karaf (because it provides easy way to automate commands and easy management of bundles) . I'll set it up with a shared bundle store, so whenever I update a bundle, all runtimes will pick it up. Karaf is designed to support executing commands from scripts, so it shouldn't be hard to write the required scripts, which will manage the system. However, you won't get distributed transaction. At some point of time, there would be versions mismatch and I don't think that there is a solution to this currently.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at more "managed" solutions made for cloud-like environments: [Apache ACE](http://incubator.apache.org/ace/) or its bigger brother [Amdatu](http://www.amdatu.org/confluence/display/Amdatu/Welcome+to+Amdatu).

Apache ACE turns a single OSGi Containers into managed containers whose state can be controlled from a single administration point.
Amdatu is a more complete framework that includes ACE for provisioning but adds horizontal functionality.

Comment: Note that Apache ACE just graduated as a Top Level Apache Project, so the link (still in Incubator space) may not be valid for long time.

Comment: The link will remain valid and simply redirect to the new location.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of managing large numbers of bundles, look at Karaf features - they greatly simplify handling largely suites of bundles.

For the distributed side of things, take a look at the Karaf subproject [Cellar](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/cellar/latest-4/), it's clustering Karaf using HazelCast (and it installs in Karaf via the features mechanism).

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about enterprise ready - meaning "robust" - distributed OSGi runtimes - then have a look at the Paremus Service Fabric. We've been doing this since 2005 :)

The Service Fabric's provisioning / management architecture is extremely scalable (>> 1,000's of containers), responsive and stable! Several years development and commercial runtime experience underpinning this product. The Service Fabric architecture supports multiple concurrent distributed OSGi based applications. The Service Fabric's architecture is OBR centric; our lead engineer was responsible recent OSGi Alliance OBR specification activities.

The Service Fabric message backplane leverages the DDS messaging protocol - which IMO is the natural partner for distributed OSGi. The Paremus RSA (remote service implementation) is a clean room implementation of the standard - which is highly robust, light weight and allows dynamic plug ability of protocol and distribution providers. The default discovery provider - is again DDS.

Finally - and Service Fabric works out of the box.

Comment: The following links may be of interest - http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/the-dawn-of-composite-clouds-why-osgi-is-the-most-important-ingredient-in-the-next-generation-of-java-compute-cloud-richard-nicholson & http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/cloud-osgi-the-dawn-of-composite-clouds & and a slight more abstract presentation http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/complexity-components-clouds-paremus

Answer (score 1):

In [Gyrex](http://www.eclipse.org/gyrex) we use p2 to distribute bundles across different nodes of a cluster. It's possible to control which bundles should be provisioned to which node by using the node tags and LDAP filter expressions (common in OSGi). For example, it's possible to install (and activate) web bundles only on web nodes.

Support for distributed services is [not available out-of-the box](http://bugs.eclipse.org/383415). ECF needs to be integrated manually.

Comment: as of April 2016 it seems that work goes only on server http://git.eclipse.org/c/gyrex/

Comment: All code has been merged into one single Git repository for easier maintenance.